# How to run multiple interactive command line by line (not as script)?

Tags: bash

I have multiple commands to run in bash. Because these cmd are interactive by nature so I can't put them in a script and run as script (no for `./cmds`)

But I want to put them in a file (like text file) line-by-line and run them as command line-by-line (not script):

```
$ bash < my_cmds_as_text_line_by_line.txt


#my_cmds_as_text_line_by_line.txt
cmd1
cmd2
cmd3
```

**QUESTION**
Is above execution same as:

```
bash -c cmd1
bash -c cmd2
bash -c cmd3
```

Comment: You can absolutely use interactive commands in a script. If you use an interactive command like `nano /etc/motd` or `bash` or `hangman`, the script will run the program, let the user interact with it, and then continue with the next command once they exit the invoked tool.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is "No, the two are not the same".

If you run:

```
bash < my_cmds_as_text_line_by_line.txt
```

where the mentioned file contains:

```
cmd1
cmd2
cmd3
```

that is NOT the same as:

```
bash -c "cmd1"
bash -c "cmd2"
bash -c "cmd3"
```

because each line now executes in a brand new `bash` shell of its own, not one that has potentially been affected by a previous command which may have:

- changed directory
- changed an environment variable

Imagine `cmd1` was `cd /usr`, in the second scheme that would change directory to `/usr` then exit the `bash` shell and start a new one - somewhere else altogether.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the difference Mark Setchell pointed out (running separate commands with `bash -c` not keeping environment changes), there's another important difference: using `bash <file` redirects standard input from the file (that's what `<` does), meaning that (almost) all input -- not just commands -- is read from the file rather than the terminal. For instance, suppose you had this as the file:

```
read -p "Enter some text: " input
echo "You entered: $input"
echo "No, really, you entered: $input"
```

If you run these with `bash <file`, the `read` command reads from the file rather than the terminal:

```
$ bash <script.sh
No, really, you entered: echo "You entered: $input"
```

In case it's not clear what happened here, I'll explain in more detail. `bash` ran with the script file as its input. It read the first line, and executed it as a command. That was the `read` command, so it read a line of input *from the file* (getting the second line of the file), and assigned that to the variable `input`. Then it read the next (third) line and executed it as a command again.

On the other hand, let's try it line-by-line with `bash -c`:

```
$ bash -c 'read -p "Enter some text: " input'
Enter some text: Hey, look, it's actually letting me enter something here!
$ bash -c 'echo "You entered: $input"'
You entered: 
$ bash -c 'echo "No, really, you entered: $input"'
No, really, you entered:
```

What happened here is what Mark described. The first command successfully read from the terminal, and assigned the input to the variable `input`. But the second and third commands had new environments, which didn't have that variable set, so they printed it as blank.

Which brings me to a better way to run the commands in a file: run it with `bash file` (note the lack of `<`). This tells bash to open the file and read commands *but nothing else* from it. Standard input is not affected, so interactive commands in the script can read from the terminal, just like normal:

```
$ bash script.sh
Enter some text: Hey, look, it's actually letting me enter something here!
You entered: Hey, look, it's actually letting me enter something here!
No, really, you entered: Hey, look, it's actually letting me enter something here!
```

But there's an even better way to do it: add a shebang line, make the script executable, and run it with `./file`. This allows people to run the script without worrying about what scripting language it's written in. This is considered the normal way to run scripts, and there's a reason for this: it's generally better than the other ways.